# Parsing a CSV file in UNIX , but also handling data within " "

Tags: unix

I am trying to parse a CSV file in UNIX using AWK or shell scripting. But I am facing a issue here. 
If the data is within quotes(",") then I want to replace the comma(,) with a blank space and remove the quotes. Also , such data might occur multiple times in one single record.

For eg:  Consider this input

20,Manchester,"Barclays,League",xyz,123,"95,some,data",

the output  should be as follows

20,Manchester,Barclays League,xyz,123,95 some data,

How can it be done b basic UNIX commands or scripting.
Please help me on this ....

Comment: Have you considered writing your script in Python and using its `csv` module: it can deal with these cases (`dialect=Excel` by default, I think)? Python is available on most Unix systems, sometimes installed by default on Linux.

Comment: Seconded @Bruno's comments, although I'd have suggested [Perl](http://perl.org) and the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) module. Using a language where there is a high quality CSV parser already available will save countless headaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input.csv python -c \
'import csv,sys;f=csv.reader(sys.stdin);print '\
'("\n".join(",".join(entry.replace(",", " ") for entry in line) for line in f))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it using `sed` in shell:

```
sed -i '.orig' -e ':a' -e 's/^\([^"]*\)"\([^,"]*\)"\(.*\)$/\1\2\3/g' \
-e 's/^\([^"]*\)"\([^,"]*\),\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)$/\1"\2 \3"\4/;ta' file.csv
```